# Unable to read files in JBOSS5

Tags: java, web-applications, war, jboss5.x

I have a file named `configuration.xml` which resides in `classes` folder of my `WEB-INF` directory

I try to read it using `class.getResource("/configuration.xml").path();`

But am not able to read the file as it is inside the WAR file.

Can any one suggest me on how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getResourceAsStream()`, rather than `getResource()`.  This will give you a direct `InputStream` reference, rather than a URL, and will work for resources packed inside a JAR/WAR.